# cascading values in a ul >li hierarchy with javascript / jquery closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have ul > li > ul > li hierarchy. Each li has input text box associated to it. I want to attach onchange event handlers to each input element so that when that element is changed all subsequent children input elements also inherit this value. I want to implement a *closure* around the innermost .bind function for each element so that I can pass in the parent input **value** on runtime. How best is this accomplished?

```
var $generatedFeatureTree = $('.generated','#feature_weights');

// Get all input text boxes in the top level div
var generatedWeights = $generatedFeatureTree.find('input[type="text"]');

for(var i =0; i< generatedWeights.length; ++i){

    var $this = $(generatedWeights[i]);
    var value = $this.val();

    $this.bind('change',function(value){
        $$this = $(this);

        // get all children input elements of this node by traversing a parent 'li'
        // and getting the lone 'ul' child
        var children = $$this.parent('li').children('ul').find('input[type="text"]');

        for(var j=0;j<children.length;++j){
            $$$this = $(children[j]);
            $$$this.val(value);
        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want, but I think you have an overengineered solution there.  Couldn't you just do it like this?

```
var myInputs = $('input[type=text]');  //use whatever selector you need to grab ALL textboxes
myInputs.change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').find('input[type=text]').val($(this).val());
});
```

It doesn't really matter to you what level the input is at, all you need to be able to do is set all the inputs below that one to the same value.  As such, you can attach the same change function to all the inputs.  My function just looks for a `<ul>` that is a sibling to the input, finds all the textboxes in that `<ul>`, and sets them to the same value as the parent text box.  I think that's what you were looking to accomplish.

Here's a live demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/wXqcE/

Comment: Yes thanks, this works in my current scenario. I was thinking that I have to iterate over item set returned by find('input[type=text]') one by one. Although, I am not sure though why the variable value is not getting passed in my original solution?

Comment: I'm not 100% positive about this, but I think the problem is that the closure you created doesn't ever change the value that's being passed in.  The `value` var is set when you first run that script, and then never modified, so assuming the textbox is empty when that script runs, it would just keep passing an empty value when the change event fires.